# numpy array with the second dimension empty

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Although I have seen some answers for this question, I was wondering if there's any better way to solve this problem.

For example,

```
N = 15
A = np.repeat(1/N, N)
```

if I do this the result will have shape (15, )

If I want the shape to be (15,1), I think I can do

```
A = np.repeat(1/N, N)[:,np.newaxis]
```

I also have the same kind of problems with

```
np.ones(N); np.zeros(N)
```

and I can probably make the second dimension as 1, by using "np.newaxis"

But my question is, are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Try A=A.reshape((15,1))

Comment: Using `np.newaxis` is a good tool for this task (though I use the shorter `None`).  There's a minimal speed penalty.  The idiom is clear (to experienced users).  And it is useful in many other circumstances.

Comment: @hpaulj , please explain me why is my explanation is not optimal?

Comment: As written your reshape needs to know the length of `A`.  There is a `-1` shortcut, which often puzzles beginners.  Timings for a small task like this are tricky (we are just making a `view`), but `newaxis` times faster.  But for me it's mainly a matter of readability.  The purpose of `newaxis` is clear.

Comment: Technically a dimension of size `1` is not `empty`.

Comment: Thank you all for the nice comments and answers. I am new to python, so when I first got the second axis as empty, I was a bit surprised and I thought maybe I did not use the commands right or there might be extra options that I should use.. But now I understand that in python I have to distinguish these, and functions will react differently.. For example: I was using the function np.diag(), and as you can imagine, depending on the types of input, it can create totally different results. Now I solved this problem with np.diagflat() :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `np.ones` and `np.zeros` you can pass a tuple specifying the shape of the output array:

```
np.ones((N, 1)); np.zeros((N, 1))
```

For `np.repeat`, you probably need to pass an array (or list) that already has two dimensions and then repeat along the desired axis:

```
>>> np.repeat([[1./N]], N, axis=0)
array([[ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667]])
```

The syntax is, however, more difficult to read/understand, and promises no extra performances. You could stick to adding a new axis to the array like you've shown.

Comment: Adding the extra dimensions to `ones` makes sense.  Tweaking `repeat` like this is slower and harder to understand.  `np.full` is faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for noting. Didn't actually time it to see which works faster. Added some comments about this.